# PIG script for creating IDxCITY matrix from given csv file

Tags: apache-pig, flatten

I have an input file includes ID,CITY and Count information as below and I want to create a csv file which includes ID and count numbers for each CITY. Count will be written as '0' if ID doesnt watched with the CITY. I tried to generate a pig script using group by, cogroup and flatten but couldnt make it to give this sample output.

How can I write a pig script for this?

INPUT(ID,CITY,COUNT):

```
00004589,IZMIR,2
00005275,KOCAELI,1
00005275,ISTANBUL,1
00008523,ESKISEHIR,2
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID,IZMIR,ISTANBUL,ESKISEHIR,KOCAELI
00004589,2,0,0,0
00005275,0,1,0,1
00008523,0,0,2,0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script for creating matrix:

DATA = load '/tmp/data.csv' Using PigStorage(',') as (ID:chararray,CITY:chararray,COUNT:chararray);

ESKISEHIR = filter DATA by (CITY matches 'ESKISEHIR');

ISTANBUL = filter DATA by (CITY matches 'ISTANBUL');

IZMIR = filter DATA by (CITY matches 'IZMIR');

KOCAELI = filter DATA by (CITY matches 'KOCAELI');

IDLIST = foreach DATA generate $0 as ID;

IDLIST = distinct IDLIST;

COGROUPED = cogroup IDLIST by $0,IZMIR by $0,ISTANBUL by $0,ESKISEHIR by $0,KOCAELI by $0;

CG_CITY = foreach COGROUPED generate FLATTEN($1),FLATTEN ((IsEmpty($2.$2) ? {('0')} : $2.$2)),FLATTEN ((IsEmpty($3.$2) ? {('0')} : $3.$2)),FLATTEN ((IsEmpty($4.$2) ? {('0')} : $4.$2)),FLATTEN ((IsEmpty($5.$2) ? {('0')} : $5.$2));

STORE CG_CITY INTO '/tmp/id_city_matrix' USING PigStorage(',');